# Add namespace to element and serialize without alias

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I want to set a namespace to a wrapper. But instead of serializing it with a alias, I need it to be on the wrapper element itself.

What i get is following

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:my-namepsace.com/asdf">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <urn:YVDMS_TASK>
        ...
     </urn:YVDMS_TASK>
   </soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Envelope>
```

But i want it like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <YVDMS_TASK xmlns="urn:my-namepsace.com/asdf">
        ...
     </YVDMS_TASK>
   </soapenv:Body>
<soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  I think you are adding the namespace to the serializer instead of adding the URL to the classes.  When adding to the serializer it is putting the namespace in the root instead of in the proper descendant.

Comment: "I need it to be on the wrapper element itself." strongly suggests that whatever is processing this is *not* built correctly. From the XML information perspective, the two samples are the same. Which means that someone's hand-rolled some XML processing code, probably using string mangling, rather than using tooling *designed* for working with XML.

Comment: Yes. I don't think that the other part is really spec complient

Answer (score 0):

The First image specifies ServiceContract's namespace, to specify namespace of your body ,you could try message contract.
But you should pay attention that the returned type should also has the attribute MessageContract.

Below is my code.

```
 [MessageContract(WrapperNamespace = "www.message.com")]

public class Employee
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "www.message.com")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "www.message.com")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "www.message.com")]
    public string Department { get; set; }
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "www.message.com")]
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}


[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmployeeService
{
   [OperationContract]
    Employee GetEmployee(Employee employee);
}

 public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
{
    public Employee GetEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        return employee;
    }
}
```

When I call the service at client

```
  using (ChannelFactory<IEmployeeService> ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IEmployeeService>("emp"))
        {
            // ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new MyEndpointBehavior());
            IEmployeeService employeeService = ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            employeeService.GetEmployee(new Employee() { Name = "abc", Department = "dep", Grade = "male", Id = "1er" });
            // List<Employee> list=  employeeService.GetList();
            Console.Read();
        }
```

The result.
[image]

For more information , please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts